# Unity - enable VR support for just one scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr-sdk

I'm using unity (version 2019.1.1) to build Android/IOS application, 
I opened a 3D project though all of the scenes in the projects are 2D except for the video player which suppose to have 2 modes VR and 360 display

So I need VR Support for just one scene (which is the video player, currently build with google-vr-sdk). The rest of the scenes are 2D and don't require VR enabling.

However, if I choose not to enable VR settings (XR settings) the 360 video does not move via motion sensors but the rest of the application works fine. If I do enable the VR settings I don't see the home-screen at all.

My current work-around is to develop two applications, one containing just the video and the other application that has the rest of the features. But I wouldn't know how to connect them. I want to know if there is a way to do both in one application? and If not how can I connect the 2 projects ?

UPDATE : I tried to export the VR Player Project as a custom unity package and then import it into my main project but then again all the 2D pages work as expected but the player does not response to movements

Comment: Perhaps this link would help : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.XRSettings-enabled.html , so enable when on that particular scene and disable otherwise

Comment: seems to be exactly what I needed but when implementing this the movie remains 2D

Comment: Have you tried turning them on before loading the new scene?
Also, the reason for not seeing home scene could be your camera object in the home scene. Is it controlled/affected in any way by the sensors?

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer from a guy in reddit. it orked great for me ! :

Add virtuality support in the XR settings bet set None above cardboard(I'm assuming this is cardboard?).

Then either use this to Start VR:

```
IEnumerator EnableCardboard() {
    // Empty string loads the "None" device.
    XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("CardBoard");
    // Must wait one frame after calling `XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName()`.
    yield return null;
    // Not needed, since loading the None (`""`) device takes care of 
    this.XRSettings.enabled = true;
   }
```

Or this to Stop VR:

```
public IEnumerator StopCardboard(){
    XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("");
    yield return null;
    XRSettings.enabled = false;
    ResetCameras();
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
}

void ResetCameras() {
    // Camera looping logic copied from GvrEditorEmulator.cs
    for (int i = 0; i < Camera.allCameras.Length; i++) {
        Camera cam = Camera.allCameras[i];
        if (cam.enabled && cam.stereoTargetEye != StereoTargetEyeMask.None) {
            // Reset local position.
            // Only required if you change the camera's local position while in 2D mode.
            cam.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

            // Reset local rotation.
            // Only required if you change the camera's local rotation while in 2D mode.
            cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;

            // No longer needed, see issue github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/628.
            // cam.ResetAspect();

            // No need to reset `fieldOfView`, since it's reset automatically.
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to call them as coroutines 
now I only need to take care of the splash screen